# Solve the PDE $(xz-y)p+(yz-x)q=xy-z$ using lagrange method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE,

$$(xz-y)p+(yz-x)q=xy-z$$where $p=z_x,\quad q=z_y$

Now having a hard time to get two solution from,

$$\frac{dx}{xz-y}=\frac{dy}{yz-x}=\frac{dz}{xy-z}$$

I can't think of any multipliers trick which can help me to get one. In fact, $dx-dy$ or $dx+dy$ also couldn't help here. I guess the $xy-z$ term is the main culprit.

Any solution or hint will be appreciated. It will be a great help if you also describe how to guess the trick (if you used so).

Thanks in advance.

### update

In fact, I got two more problems where I faced the similar issue:

$$\left(x z+y^{2}\right) p+\left(y z-2 x^{2}\right) z=-\left(2 x y+z^{2}\right)\qquad (1)$$
gives
$$\frac{d x}{x z+y^2}=\frac{d y}{y z-2 x^{2}}=\frac{d z}{-\left(2 x y+z^{2}\right)}$$

---

$$(y+3 z)p+(z+5 x)q=x+7 y\qquad (2)$$

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{d x}{y+3 z}=\frac{d y}{z+5 x}=\frac{d z}{x+7 y}\\
\implies&\frac{d x-3d y}{y-15x}=\frac{d y-5d z}{z-7 y}=\frac{d z-7d x}{x-21 z}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: a PDE is supposed to contain partial derivatives... My hint is that you do not have a PDE.

Comment: @PierreCarre $p = z_{x}, q = z_{y}$

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{x dx}{x^{2} z - xy} = \frac{y dy}{y^{2} z - yx} = \frac{x dx - y dy}{x^{2} z - y^{2} z} = \frac{d(x^{2} - y^{2})}{2(x^{2} - y^{2})z}$$

Comment: @mattos We should not have to guess from the solution...

Comment: @PierreCarre I agree, it should be explicit, but in fairness using $p$ and $q$ is a widely used notation.

Comment: I update the post with adding the meaning of those notations @PierreCarre.

Comment: I also tried similar thing like $\frac{ydx-xdy}{x^2-y^2}$, but the $z$ variable still here in your hint. Then how to integral that? From my understanding, there shouldn't be any other variable @mattos

Comment: You need to manipulate the other equalities (try $dx, dz$ and $dy, dz$ combinations) in a similar way and then set them equal to the result I gave above.

Comment: $d y, d z$ combination with $y, z$ multipliers give me $\frac{y d y-z d z}{y^2{z}-x y-x y z-z^{2}}$ which I guess won't work with $\frac{d\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right)}{2\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right) z}$, similar with $d x, d z$ combination with $x, z$ multipliers @mattos

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer rather expanding the @ShengtongZhang's one as the OP commented there,

characteristic equation of that PDE,

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{xz-y}=\frac{dy}{yz-x}=\frac{dz}{xy-z}=dt\\
&x'=xz-y,\quad y'=yz-x, \quad z'=xy-z
\end{align}
$$
Now, inspecting the $x'y-y'x$ term,

$$
\begin{align}
x'y-y'x&=(xz-y)y-(yz-x)x\\
&=xyz-y^2-xyz+x^2\\
&=x^2-y^2 \text{(free of $z$ variable)}
\end{align}
$$

Which give some idea to guess one solution as $\frac{x}{y}$,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)&=\frac{x'y-y'x}{y^2}\\
&=\frac{x^2-y^2}{y^2} \text{(solvable)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

An idea: WLOG let $dt = \frac{dx}{xy - z}$. Then
$$\frac{d\frac{x}{y}}{dt} = \frac{x'y - y'x}{y^2} = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{y^2} = (x/y)^2 - 1.$$
So you can now find $\frac{x}{y} = \coth(t + C)$. But I don't know how to go further.

Comment: I didn't understand $\frac{d\frac{x}{y}}{dt}$, could you add some more details @ShengtongZhang

Comment: Ok this is not really a solution.